# Click event not working with dynamically generated Elements in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

My question is how can we enable click event of dynamically generated HTML element using `ElementRef`.

HTML Code which is dynamically appended.

```
<ul class="list-group" style="border-radius: 4px;">
    <div class="file_list_event">
    <li class="list-group-item">        
        <button (click)="save_event_btn_app()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger  delete_file_event pull-right" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Delete</button>
        </div>
    </li>                   
</ul>
```

`li` is dynamically generated after service call. 
So, I'm not able to Generate the click event because it's a dynamically generated element.

So, for that I tried below code.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}


  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.delete_file_event')
                                .addEventListener('click', this.save_event_btn_app.bind(this)); 
 // Above code I have added just after the append code.

save_event_btn_app(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

But still I got the same error that,

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Note:- I'm not sharing the dynamic html generation code because it's not necessary here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this error by adding a check that el is not null before adding an event listener,

```
let el =  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.delete_file_event');
if(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', this.save_event_btn_app.bind(this));
}
```

However to see why it is null , you need to add your dynamic generation code

Comment: It worked. Thank you brother for this very quick answer.

Comment: How can I add click event with parameter because it shows click but When I'm passing arguments its not getting value with argument.

Comment: what is the argument?

Comment: In Button click it's a argument with string `save_event_btn_app('string')`. Which is in Button from dynamically generate HTML.

Comment: @Bhavin : you store in property and used when function get fired.